# Shortest Sudoku Solver in Python - How does it work?

Tags: python, algorithm

I was playing around with my own Sudoku solver and was looking for some pointers to good and fast design when I came across this:

```
def r(a):i=a.find('0');~i or exit(a);[m
in[(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3)or a[j]for
j in range(81)]or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])for m in'%d'%5**18]
from sys import*;r(argv[1])
```

My own implementation solves Sudokus the same way I solve them in my head but how does this cryptic algorithm work?

http://scottkirkwood.blogspot.com/2006/07/shortest-sudoku-solver-in-python.html

Comment: that looks like an entry to the obfuscated perl contest! I thought one of the points of python was to write clean code that could be easily understood :)

Comment: That python doesn't look like its indented correctly. :/

Comment: This is yet another proof that you can write incomprehensible code in any language.

Comment: I think this must have been a code golf answer.

Comment: BTW I'm pretty sure this was for a competition to write the shortest possible sudoku solver.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Well, you can make things a little easier by fixing up the syntax:

```
def r(a):
  i = a.find('0')
  ~i or exit(a)
  [m in[(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3)or a[j]for j in range(81)] or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])for m in'%d'%5**18]
from sys import *
r(argv[1])
```

Cleaning up a little:

```
from sys import exit, argv
def r(a):
  i = a.find('0')
  if i == -1:
    exit(a)
  for m in '%d' % 5**18:
    m in[(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3) or a[j] for j in range(81)] or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])

r(argv[1])
```

Okay, so this script expects a command-line argument, and calls the function r on it.  If there are no zeros in that string, r exits and prints out its argument.

> (If another type of object is passed,
>   None is equivalent to passing zero,
>   and any other object is printed to
>   sys.stderr  and results in an exit
>   code of 1. In particular,
>   sys.exit("some error message") is a
>   quick way to exit a program when an
>   error occurs. See
>   http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-sys.html)

I guess this means that zeros correspond to open spaces, and a puzzle with no zeros is solved.  Then there's that nasty recursive expression.

The loop is interesting: `for m in'%d'%5**18`

Why 5**18? It turns out that `'%d'%5**18` evaluates to `'3814697265625'`.  This is a string that has each digit 1-9 at least once, so maybe it's trying to place each of them.  In fact, it looks like this is what `r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])` is doing: recursively calling r, with the first blank filled in by a digit from that string.  But this only happens if the earlier expression is false.  Let's look at that:

`m in [(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3) or a[j] for j in range(81)]`

So the placement is done only if m is not in that monster list.  Each element is either a number (if the first expression is nonzero) or a character (if the first expression is zero).  m is ruled out as a possible substitution if it appears as a character, which can only happen if the first expression is zero.  When is the expression zero?

It has three parts that are multiplied:

- `(i-j)%9` which is zero if i and j are a multiple of 9 apart, i.e. the same column.
- `(i/9^j/9)` which is zero if i/9 == j/9, i.e. the same row.
- `(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3)` which is zero if both of these are zero:
- - `i/27^j^27` which is zero if i/27 == j/27, i.e. the same block of three rows
- - `i%9/3^j%9/3` which is zero if i%9/3 == j%9/3, i.e. the same block of three columns

If any of these three parts is zero, the entire expression is zero.  In other words, if i and j share a row, column, or 3x3 block, then the value of j can't be used as a candidate for the blank at i.  Aha!

```
from sys import exit, argv
def r(a):
  i = a.find('0')
  if i == -1:
    exit(a)
  for m in '3814697265625':
    okay = True
    for j in range(81):
      if (i-j)%9 == 0 or (i/9 == j/9) or (i/27 == j/27 and i%9/3 == j%9/3):
        if a[j] == m:
          okay = False
          break
    if okay:
      # At this point, m is not excluded by any row, column, or block, so let's place it and recurse
      r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])

r(argv[1])
```

Note that if none of the placements work out, r will return and back up to the point where something else can be chosen, so it's a basic depth first algorithm.

Not using any heuristics, it's not particularly efficient.  I took this puzzle from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku):

```
$ time python sudoku.py 530070000600195000098000060800060003400803001700020006060000280000419005000080079
534678912672195348198342567859761423426853791713924856961537284287419635345286179

real    0m47.881s
user    0m47.223s
sys 0m0.137s
```

Addendum: How I would rewrite it as a maintenance programmer (this version has about a 93x speedup :)

```
import sys

def same_row(i,j): return (i/9 == j/9)
def same_col(i,j): return (i-j) % 9 == 0
def same_block(i,j): return (i/27 == j/27 and i%9/3 == j%9/3)

def r(a):
  i = a.find('0')
  if i == -1:
    sys.exit(a)

  excluded_numbers = set()
  for j in range(81):
    if same_row(i,j) or same_col(i,j) or same_block(i,j):
      excluded_numbers.add(a[j])

  for m in '123456789':
    if m not in excluded_numbers:
      # At this point, m is not excluded by any row, column, or block, so let's place it and recurse
      r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if len(sys.argv) == 2 and len(sys.argv[1]) == 81:
    r(sys.argv[1])
  else:
    print 'Usage: python sudoku.py puzzle'
    print '  where puzzle is an 81 character string representing the puzzle read left-to-right, top-to-bottom, and 0 is a blank'
```

Comment: ...which just goes to show that you can still write bad code in python if you try really hard :-)

Comment: Just for explicitness, you might want to change `i%9/3 == j%9/3` to `(i%9) / 3 == (j%9) / 3`. I know you're supposed to know the order of operators by heart, but it's easy to forget and makes it a bit easier to scan.

Comment: What if the numbers passed to function are wrong? Will this go forever or will it terminate itself after all combinations tried?

Comment: @GundarsMēness At each point in the recursion, a single empty position is handled. If no valid digit for this position can be found, the function simply returns. That means, if no valid digit for the first empty position can be found (i.e. the input was an invalid sudoku) the whole program returns without output (`sys.exit(a)` is never reached)

Comment: So everyone really seems to like this implementation, both here and on other sites, but the problem is that it doesnt work.  If you test the code with the example sudoku from wikipedia, it fills the puzzle with tons of illegal moves (i.e. 3 1's right next to each other) etc.

Comment: @JoshBibb I know this is an old post, but that error is occurring for you because this was written for Python2 and you're running it in Python3. Replace all the `/` operators in `same_row`, `same_col`, and `same_block` with `//` operators and you'll get the right answer.

Comment: what happens if excluded_numbers is a smaller set, and more than 1 values are possible for an empty position? you shouldn't be using the first non-excluded numbers when you write "for m in '123456789':  if m not in excluded_numbers:". The solution posted here doesn't check for uniqueness and will end up with an error at a later stage. Let me know if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 10):

unobfuscating it:

```
def r(a):
    i = a.find('0') # returns -1 on fail, index otherwise
    ~i or exit(a) # ~(-1) == 0, anthing else is not 0
                  # thus: if i == -1: exit(a)
    inner_lexp = [ (i-j)%9*(i/9 ^ j/9)*(i/27 ^ j/27 | i%9/3 ^ j%9/3) or a[j] 
                   for j in range(81)]  # r appears to be a string of 81 
                                        # characters with 0 for empty and 1-9 
                                        # otherwise
    [m in inner_lexp or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:]) for m in'%d'%5**18] # recurse
                            # trying all possible digits for that empty field
                            # if m is not in the inner lexp

from sys import *
r(argv[1]) # thus, a is some string
```

So, we just need to work out the inner list expression. I know it collects the digits set in the line -- otherwise, the code around it makes no sense. However, I have no real clue how it does that (and Im too tired to work out that binary fancyness right now, sorry)

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but line 3 is *or* exit, so I think your logic's in reverse

Comment: Assume i = -1. Then ~i = 0, and 0 or foo causes foo to be evaluated.
On the other hand, if i != -1, then ~i will be non-zero, thus, the first part of the or will be true, which causes the second parameter of the or to be NOT evaluated, due to short circuited evaluation.

Answer (score 7):

`r(a)` is a recursive function which attempts to fill in a `0` in the board in each step.

`i=a.find('0');~i or exit(a)` is the on-success termination.  If no more `0` values exist in the board, we're done.

`m` is the current value we will try to fill the `0` with.

`m
in[(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3)or a[j]for
j in range(81)]` evaluates to truthy if it is obivously incorrect to put `m` in the current `0`.  Let's nickname it "is_bad".  This is the most tricky bit. :)

`is_bad or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:]` is a conditional recursive step.  It will recursively try to evaluate the next `0`  in the board iff the current solution candidate appears to be sane.

`for m in '%d'%5**18` enumerates all the numbers from 1 to 9 (inefficiently).

Comment: He could have used 14 ** 7 * 9 instead of 5 ** 18.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the short sudoku solvers just recursively try every possible legal number left until they have successfully filled the cells.  I haven't taken this apart, but just skimming it, it looks like that's what it does.