# sudoku obfuscated python -> perl translation

Tags: python, perl, translate

Anybody care to translate this into obfuscated perl? It's written in Python taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201461/shortest-sudoku-solver-in-python-how-does-it-work)

```
def r(a):i=a.find('0');~i or exit(a);[m
in[(i-j)%9*(i/9^j/9)*(i/27^j/27|i%9/3^j%9/3)or a[j]for
j in range(81)]or r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])for m in'%d'%5**18]
from sys import*;r(argv[1])
```

I realize it's just for fun :)

Comment: Looks pretty obfuscated to me!

Comment: ofuscated code is wasted code. It's just for fun and not worth translating into a different language.

Comment: "Obfuscated Perl" is redundant!

Comment: @Mike: You deserve many more +1's for that.

Comment: @Mike Daniels: if that's how you feel, your comments on anything tagged perl are probably not going to be very helpful; maybe you could just avoid reading perl questions.

Comment: @ysth:  I think @Mike Daniels was repeating a common joke.

Comment: @Mike Daniels: the problem is your "Joke" is actually believed by people to the point its a common myth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755168/perl-myths

Comment: also, had you taken the time to see the original post, you would have seen the attached perl version: http://scottkirkwood.blogspot.com/2006/07/shortest-sudoku-solver-in-python.html

Comment: http://www.ecclestoad.co.uk/blog/2005/06/02/sudoku_solver_in_three_lines_explained.html  # and here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub r{($a=shift)=~/0/g?my$i=pos:die$a;T:for$m(1..9){($i-$_)%9*(int($i/9)^int($_/9))*(int($i/27)^int($_/27)|int($i%9/3)^int($_%9/3))||$a=~/^.{$_}$m/&&next T,for 0..80;substr($a,$i,1)=$m;r($a)}}r@ARGV
```

The braindead translation.  Longer, since Python 2's `/` is integer division while Perl's is floating-point.

Answer (score 2):

There already are a few Sudoku solvers written in Obfuscated Perl, do you really want another (possibly less efficient) one?

If not...

1. De-obfuscate.
2. Rewrite in Perl.
3. Obfuscate.