# Shortest Sudoku Solver in Python

Tags: python, sudoku, brute-force, solver

I started to write my own Sudoku solver in Python but it was too slow / inelegant,
so I searched for an elegant way to solve this problem.

I stumbled upon this cryptic Sudoku solver and the very good explanation given by the community:
[Shortest Sudoku Solver in Python - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201461/shortest-sudoku-solver-in-python-how-does-it-work)
I have understood the explained and stretched out version but I have one problem with this:

When I run the version explained by Bill Barksdale with a Python version below 3.0 it takes pretty long to solve a Sudoku, but succeeds and prints out the right solution.
When I run the program with Python 3.0 or 3.4, the program is done in less than a second, but prints out a wrong solution.

I have tried to find the problem with Python > 3.0 but I have no idea.
Could someone please point out why this program is running below Python 3.0 but not above?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running his `maintainable` version from that answer?

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I think you need to also look up the meaning of elegant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem may well be the difference in the Python 3 divide operator in Python 2 `2/3 = 0` but in Python 3 `2/3 = 0.66666` which will mess up the logic nicely.  You can try adding `from __future__ import division` and running under Python 2 or by replacing all the `/`s with `//` and running under Python 3.

In general obfuscated code is also unmaintainable code so I would avoid describing it as elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did not knew this, since I am relatively new to Python. I think the maintainable version is some kind of elegant, since it is short and good to understand.